# JBoss compatible version with Java11

Tags: java, jboss, java-11

I am using JBoss 7.1 with JDK1.7. I am planning to upgrade to Java11. JBoss 7.1 is not starting. Could you please let me know which version of JBoss I have to use with Java11?

Comment: *JBoss 7.1 is not starting*, what is the error that you see? More to track here - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-15283

Comment: Getting following error:

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 2):

No, JBoss 7.1 does not support either Java 11 nor even Java 8.
Check [this post](https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279) at jboss.org for detailed information

> Recently released EAP 7.2 supports JDK 11, see https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253

Comment: Or if you are using JBoss AS then you need to use WildFly

Comment: I am using OpenJDk11. Could you please which JBoss I have to use-  either JBoss As 7.2 or JBoss EAP 7.2 or need to use WildFly?

Comment: Thanks Vadim Yangunaev